# What's going wrong with my baking?

Tags: texture-baking

I've tried baking the textures for my mesh and it's incomplete - there's hardly any pink on it whatsoever, and when I put this texture on the mesh in Roblox, it's mostly the dough colour, some black stripes and a teeny bit of pink in one place.

[image]

It gives me no errors when baking, I've used a boolean modifier to get rid of overlaps, I've removed the other objects in the scene, applied all transforms etc.

Any idea what could be going wrong here? I feel like I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: hello please share your file (share the URL it will give you once the file is downloaded): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: [Here's the link](https://pasteall.org/blend/f4843797cc054eef9d134693adac6871) - thanks for having a look for me

Comment: it seems to work fine, select one of your pink torus, shift select the yellow one, Bake. Maybe the problem is that you have several objects and you don't do it the way you're supposed to?

Comment: I've kept them as separate objects because otherwise, whenever I click bake, it says "No valid selected objects".